# Android listview hide button items when load listview

Tags: android, listview

listview consist with one button and one textview for each row and there is 10 rows. i just need to hide only 2nd row, button item from listview when load the listview from onCreate method. i coded manual button click hide method and it work perfectly but i need to be done by automatically when listview load.

My Manual method. after clicking any button it become invisible.

```
 public void HideButton(View v){
    LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
    TextView row=(TextView)llMain.getChildAt(0); 
    Button deletebtn = (Button)llMain.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    deletebtn.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
  }
```

likewise below i coded for hide the button at listview load from onCreate but it doesnt work correctly. using this code i can access the button but it isnt hide itself.

```
private void ButtonClick() {
       View v;
       TextView row;
       ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
       TextView et;
       for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
       v = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
       et = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item1);
       String row_no=et.getText().toString();
       int idd = Integer.valueOf(row_no);
       if(idd == 2){
          // LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

           Button deletebtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
           deletebtn.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);


         }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better solution would be to remove the second element from the data array that you pass to the adapter, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: no sir. for a example i said i need to hide 2nd raw button. actually im creating a social application. there are many users.when one user share a image others can reply and only they can delete their replies.  i check user from login and i do need to visible reply delete button only for loged user. other user's replies cannot modify that user.